# Entire function bounded in the upper half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $ f(z) $ be an entire function which is real on the real axis, with $ f(0) = 1 $. Assume that there is a real constant $ M $ such that $ |f(z)| \le M $ for all $ z $ satisfying $ Im(z) \ge 0 $. Evaluate
>   \begin{equation}
> \lim\limits_{x \rightarrow + \infty}{f(x)}.
> \end{equation}

---

It's obviously about Liouville's theorem, but we know nothing about $ f(z) $ in the other half-plane. I tried to consider $ g(z) = f(\sqrt{z}) $ ($ \sqrt{z} $ is a principal branch), which is bounded everywhere, but $ \sqrt{z} $ is not entire (it is not even defined on $ [0; +\infty)\ ) $ and therefore $ g(z) $ is not entire. I would also be very grateful if someone told me some properties of *real* entire functions - I found almost nothing about them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but we know nothing about $f(z)$ in the other half-plane.

We do:

> Let $f(z)$ be an entire function which is real on the real axis

That means we have

$$f(z) = \overline{f(\overline{z})}$$

by the identity theorem, and hence a global bound.